# For Java mail API Pop3 Folder

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

For Java mail API Pop3 Folder: After getting the Unique Identifier List, how do you receive email from the servers without duplicating the already existing messages in an inbox and only retrieving new messages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaMail get only new messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531694/javamail-get-only-new-messages)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you have to keep track of the UIDs for the messages you've already seen and only retrieve messages you haven't seen.  See the [javadocs for the com.sun.mail.pop3 package](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html).

Comment: Thank you. I will check again the Javadoc.